# Make Error with Osmo Trx

Tags: installation, makefile, software-defined-radio

I am working on a project with the Beaglebone Black and ran into an issue. As part of my project, I would like to use OpenBTS to communicate over the GSM network. However, because the Beaglebone is ARM based, the Transceiver52M that ships with OpenBTS is unusable. Therefore, I need to install an ARM friendly transceiver. The transceiver that I think will do best is Osmo-Trx.

I followed the instructions on their website: 
http://openbsc.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/OsmoTRX

However, when it came to making the project, got an error and am really stuck. When I do the command "make" after "./configure --with-neon", I get the error:

> make: ***No rule to make target '/Makefile.common', needed by 'Makefile.in'. Stop.

Would anyone be able to help me fix this. I've search around and can't find any applicable answers. I would really appreciate it. Thank you so much in advance!

P.S. All the source code for the OsmoTRX can be found at: https://github.com/osmocom/osmo-trx

Comment: Hm, why is Transceiver52M unusable?

Comment: have you done `autoreconf -i` before `configure --with-neon`?

Comment: Ping! has anything happened? Problem solved?

Comment: Thank you so much for checking back in! I really appreciate it! Below, is the final solution to your question

Answer (score 1):

A missing Makefile is often caused by a missed/failed step in the autotools process.

My suspcion is that you either forgot to run `autoreconf -i` or it wasn't successfull. Try

```
cd osmo-trx
git clean -xdf ##Attention: clean slate afterwards!
autoreconf -i ##make sure it reports success
./configure --with-neon ## make sure it reports success
make ## make sure it reports success
sudo make install
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I really appreciate it! I tried this, but it didn't end up working. I'm not sure what the problem was. After continuing to run into problems with my operating system in addition to this one already, I decided to reinstall the OS and re download Osmo Trx. I eventually was able to get to the make stage of the installation and ran into some bugs in the code - the compiler was catching on some errors. So I did some research and went to another forum and posted my problem:
http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/168164-make-error-osmo-trx.html#post1240907

Comment: The solution (I believe among some other, more simple errors) was able to be edited and fixed. After making it again, all seemed to work so far and it appeared to install properly. However, more testing will determine if that is the case :)

Comment: If you think that is a bug, you should **definitely** report it to osmocom -- maybe you want to discuss it on the [`OpenBSC`](https://lists.osmocom.org/mailman/listinfo/openbsc) mailing list -- they are *really* nice folks and they definitely appreciate patches and bug reports.

Comment: I tried, but they never got back to me? What are some other avenues that I could go about contacting them?

Comment: @BillyThorton Your name doesn't appear in the mailing list archives, http://lists.osmocom.org/pipermail/openbsc/ ; are you sure you were signed up to the list when you sent that mail?

Comment: I did, but perhaps something went wrong - I'll try again. Just to make sure - how do you sign up?

Comment: @BillyThorton go to  https://lists.osmocom.org/mailman/listinfo/openbsc , enter your email, a password, and hit "subscribe" :)